# Laravel Unit Test calling route with authentication

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4

I would like to create unit test in laravel 4.1. I am very new in laravel and PHP. So I would like to know how to call the route that i mentioned below.

That is my route with auth filter.

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('um',array('before' => 'auth.required'),'UMController@showAll');
```

The controller for that route is

**UMController.php**

```
public function showAll(){

      $um=Um::all();
      return $um;
    }
```

My Unit Test function that called the route is.

**UMTest.php**

```
public function testPush()
    {
        $this->be(User::find(7));
        $this->call('GET', 'um');
    }
```

But I got the error.
ErrorException: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your route is the problem

```
Route::get('um',array('before' => 'auth.required'),'UMController@showAll');
```

Try this

```
Route::get('um', array('before' => 'auth.required', 'uses' => 'UMController@showAll'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[reference](http://codeoverkill.com/question/how-to-call-route-in-laravel-with-authentication/!)

i am try many time this example it is usfull for me

```
Route::get(‘start’, array(‘before’ => ‘auth.required’ => ‘data@yourdomain’));
```